# Bring my memories about Geronimo Stilton back

Tags: code-golf, string, random

If you have read in your childhood a Geronimo Stilton's book, I am sure that you remember the style of the text, sometimes the words were decorated for making the act of reading more funny for kids: [example](https://www.google.com/search?q=geronimo%20stilton%20texto&tbm=isch&ved=2ahUKEwiSzoTxwdXwAhWJ5RoKHa0jAc0Q2-cCegQIABAA&oq=geronimo%20stilton%20texto&gs_lcp=CgNpbWcQAzoCCAA6BAgAEB46BggAEAgQHjoECAAQE1CkNFifPWCPP2gAcAB4AIABWYgB7QOSAQE2mAEAoAEBqgELZ3dzLXdpei1pbWfAAQE&sclient=img&ei=c-WkYNLIDInLa63HhOgM&bih=774&biw=1190&rlz=1C1CHBF_esES920ES920#imgrc=c_67TO5E7NrLLM).

But when you are an adult you don't have that little entertainment in your readings... why?
In a nostalgic attack I have decided to make an algorithm to create that output with every text in the world.

It's not very similar, but it's curious.

### Idea:

Make a program that with an input like this:

```
It was in the morning of June 21, and I had just set
paw in the office. Right away I could tell it wasn't
going to be a good day. My staff was running
around like a pack of rats in a maze. And everyone
was complaining about something.
"Geronimo, the air-conditioner's broken!"
yelled my secretary, Mousella MacMouser.
"Geronimo, we are run out of coffee!" shrieked
Blasco Tabasco, one of my designers.
"Geronimo, the computers are all down!"
cried my proofreader. Mickey Misprint.
```

Create an output like this:

[image: output]

or this:

[image]

(These outputs are images because there are two ways to create the output, show it in your program some way or create an output HTML like mine.) This is my raw output:

```
<font face="Verdana">It was in the morning of June 21, and I had just set </br>
paw in the <b><font face="Comic Sans MS" size="5" style="color:rgb(111,229,136);">office</font></b>. Right away I could tell it wasn't </br>
going to be a good day. My staff was <b><font face="Comic Sans MS" size="5" style="color:rgb(77,170,241);">running</font></b> </br>
around like a pack of rats in a maze. And everyone </br>
was complaining about something. </br>
"Geronimo, the air-conditioner's broken!" </br>
<b><font face="Comic Sans MS" size="5" style="color:rgb(174,152,239);">yelled</font></b> my secretary, Mousella MacMouser. </br>
"Geronimo, we are run out of coffee!" shrieked </br>
Blasco Tabasco, one of my <b><font face="Comic Sans MS" size="5" style="color:rgb(101,139,153);">designers</font></b>. </br>
"Geronimo, the computers are all down!" </br>
cried my <u><font face="Comic Sans MS" size="5" style="color:rgb(70,164,71);">proofreader</font></u>. Mickey Misprint. </br>
</font>
```

### Algorithm:

I have made an example of the algorithm (not golfed) in Java: [Here is it](https://tio.run/##xVZRk9o2EH6/X7HVQ2LXHDnIkM7dYTJNHzLpDC8l0z4AD7Isgw4jMZJ8Lrnw268rgY1d4JJpO1PPzdksu/t9@@1qzQN9pNcP6er5meXUGPjItZJireDpCvDaFEkuGBhLLd4elUhhTYUMJlYLuZjOgeqFCfe@7trbQUhhBc0/8z9tTD5ZKKlBG9glh7XS0rmoDH4tJId@rwNUpvAJljSFh8JYMNzOJIGozlpdZEPLKo/KMsF4F34Ti6UFWtItpmCqyFOwPM9BeFT5@lKqhXIsrIKEA4WFUimkdNuF8dZVm2Wesy6kI3shBdWqQOa5WLkUG8pWripNrS@WolJfkODP6MIfud4qyS8kclBMrTc5SutY0UQVKINac7vEz90LYTNSdavjJaFCXzMlU9QesfRrA4lWKy5/mJELGbaoFMeWYs2caW6p3nZgrAqDdgpjyvyz/h4CJeJr7hQDRx6FYNgizhEczFILvuLphTQfcPKYgs80cfcOIHkXj6xSbsQCSzHfK4FTsbAY4MlQnINUlS8IwJCYr3@jlco0pylWC2PBVnyLN7PBcbZdcv/3Ac@ErMZ7mClpIaOMxzPyO9cplXRGRicxeFgMl5ZLxk3cOCBds8mFDRzD8BiDsGA2nKHTH0qncYCGMBhTu@xqPC5qHYQ/3oZR76YdggcAIXTcMGdKBz4bGsEMaw7dnMuFXaItihonuEW4RGgT1yFTM6/YQpNsE6Z0MOXQR9YQ5QmEJ5wFB77DRqlnHN118Iyi@7Nf1w2JYg89LecRkjx13vHccAdduR1IBuHo7cvQTVGb17fa1HsXRoPzobXQLOdUxv6/y1OTQ5HPBjql9wATXM38LO7bqBe@BIurOBW4RKlbFxC38sW99yQhd0HL1n9PCnJHBAm/2QNfyfQGezAkURMnIqPWgflFrfHFMqHSwHjiVoX44swD92i3uXtmKlf6Ti@SgETn6uwPBmFEOv/4y/DeHddoT7nnKL9xDEfDNyfUK6/@S8P19C8H9Oryp0YSZJnoES6NY4ajb9vPV0MakzTZGsvXXdzTXb/gchnUEYfe7q7OvP/b4@oH9TBKZfvg1o6Sl84Np@uJYBfc3@50NQm3M4TfGfVpRMPJ0viwtbjiMZn3XHDrDCYIp2Le1tFtluG7AXz9CgEb3d7Aq1fAhrc/hc7CRr1@/8xRP3B1UxsHbEl16GeGtVNfaHGC747V/YXW7c5U3Cr2uofljpwI19f/S839eavk6Gj/L6uvsvbm@/JNkRg/KcFR@1qTTluhI6Pa1lhD@Nul0LICqEZ4d/X8/Bc)
This is the list of steps that you have to follow starting whit the base input:

1. Start catching a random word in position 5-20(words)
2. If the word is less or equals to 3 char long (e.g. `her`, `a`) catch the next word until you find someone whit more than 3 char
3. "Clean the word", the transformed word cant contain characters like `"` or `.`. The modified word has to starts and end whit [A-Z][a-z] and only whit that characters so... clean it if you need is the 3th step

```
Examples of this step:
if you word is    | word cleaned
------------------|----------------
"Geronimo,        | Geronimo
final.            | final
air-conditioner   | air-conditioner  (Don't remove special characters inside the word)
```

4. Put it randomly (1/3 cases) in **bold**, *cursive* or underlined (Only one at the same time for word)
5. Give the word a bigger size than the rest of the text (how much big is your election)
6. Give the word a random color (Try to make this in the widest range of colors that you can, in my code creates an RGB with Java random function in every color that goes from 0 to 255)
7. Give the word any font... (What you want, doesn't matter what you use but must be different to the text font)
8. From this word repeat the 1st step for grab a new one random word next to this

Example of algorithm:

```
In step one by a random decision between 5 and 20 you have to start in word 7 for example:
It was in the morning of *June* 21, and I had just set
paw in the office.

On time that you have modified that word you start again the random function and 
you add the result to your actual position for get the next word... the result 
of the random function this time has been 8:
It was in the morning of *June* 21, and I had just set
paw *in* the office.

But that word is 2 char long and the next one too so we take the word "office"
It was in the morning of *June* 21, and I had just set
paw in the *office.*

Office has a point at the end, lets clean it:
It was in the morning of *June* 21, and I had just set
paw in the *office*.

And the last step is modify this last word
```

Rules

- As I have said, **the output can be show in your program** (or directly in HTML if you use JavaScript or something like that) **or outputs an HTML text whit all the properties in it**.
- The **structure of the HTML can be as you want, as long as when you execute it the result should follow the rules**. Basically, you don't have to make it like my example output.
- The **base font and size can be what you want**, I have used Verdana in my example because I think that the output is more... "beautiful"? and my code is not golfed.
- If you can, put a picture to the executed HTML in your solution please.
- In reference to the randomness, the only thing that is relevant is that **the output text has different colors, styles and words every time you run the program**, if there some options are more probable  (for example red is more probable than green as a color) that doesn't matter.
- And in reference to the randomness of the colors, **it's not necessary that all colors are contemplated in the output, try to put the most colors you can**... I know that this is not very mathematically precise because is a problem to talk about colors when there are so much ways to create them (RGB, hexadecimal, HSV...) so I'm going to try to put a "minimal" rule:
- **Lets say that the "extreme" colors must have non 0 probability**, for example in RGB I mean that this colors are mandatory: `0,0,0` `255,255,255` `255,0,0`  `0,255,0` `0,0,255` `255,0,255` `0,255,255` `255,255,0` but if you want you can use too the colors in between (That is the principal idea)
  And **if for some reason you cant use that rule of extreme colors have in mind that at least the output must be 8 different colors**.
- This is code golf, so the shortest code wins.

Comment: This challenge has a lot of unqualified use of the word random.  [You should specify what you mean](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10909/56656), and maybe in the future [consider alternatives to randomness](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/18420/56656).

Comment: @WheatWizard sorry, im going to changue that

Comment: "Position 5-20" does that mean pick a random number n between 5 and 20 and apply on word number n? Your example has more than 20 words, but clearly there are words like "computers" whose position is greater than 20. What did you mean there.

Comment: @ophact Thanks for that cuestion, im going to fix that for be more clear, the idea is that you first pick a random word like you have said and then starting from that word you again pick a random word in 5-20 words from that word

Comment: can we also assume that Comic Sans is loaded as a font in HTML?

Comment: @ophact Oh, i have not think in that..., may be im going to changue that step that was "Undebatable" xd, you now can use any font that you want for the resalted words

Comment: A couple of *whit* spellings should be *with*.

Comment: @Noodle9 Ups, sorry, i have trying to do my best for write in english :P

Comment: Good for you! Also then note that the exclamation is spelt *Oops* not *Ups*. :)

Comment: should every color have a nonzero probability of appearing?

Comment: @Razetime Its a little bit trickier that question... i have write "Try to make this in the most rangue of colors that you can" trying to say that if some exactly colors left in your randomnes it dont mind... The rapid answer to that question is no, but try not to put only words in a red gradien, or gray. More variety colors = more cool

Comment: having this constraint mathematically defined, or exactly specified would be good.

Comment: @Razetime i hope that this changue help :/ its a little bit hard try to make a constant rule for all the ways that a color can be created

Comment: I wonder why people aren't answering anymore

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), <s><sub>246 244</sub></s> 232 bytes

```javascript
f=(i,j=p=0,r=_=>Math.random()*3|0,q=_=>p+=4+r()*5,x=q())=>i.replace(/[-'\w]+/g,m=>j++==p?(m[3]?[q(),`<${s="bis"[r()]} style="font:2em monospace;color:rgb(${[r()*85,r()*85,r()*85]})">${m}</${s}>`]:[++p,m])[1]:m).replace(/\n/g,"<br>")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZZJPb5tAEMXvfIoJihQIhPxrpMrJOmovVSr5UvXmoHqBAa/N7pDdJQ51/dndgaqqop4GZt@@95vRbuSrdKVVnb8wVOHxWItIpRvRiavUih9ivpB@nVlpKtJRfH776yp9GdtdIj4kljt36Zt4ieJYzFVmsWtlidHl8uLseZcnl02qxXyTJEJ0j5Fe3uaPS9amq4fTvRNhoVy4ZI/8AM4PLYqwJuNnN6hBkyHXsdd9SS3ZmW2K6HQ/is8/3qXvSn6Iw/npXh8eLtn1MF/ls2WSdKnO4@V1PtPxP6xnw0ThQ2HnYXx8lRZKELB68rCTDpQBv0ZOtkaZBqiGr71BuLlOgaeHJ1jLCja98@DQB53c/b1Bda1KzOCbatYe5E4OLC6pbyvw2LagJn9z5oOGRmdPUCBIaIgqqOSQwWLgBci6njhsb0aAQFrqObdV21HMu9iOTFb6CVWClj859BNL8BXtQAaD8XpJmqdV0wyyoJ5xSaNf838WhF/QklGa0olcKntRkqmUV3zdnjkoLG3RnITBwORYgWYyLC16aYcUFtQ77ktYyHL6tu8sd@xocRwAxlymLXk3iCchuLVVuMUq@NzycyP4LouxpsC5o5BzKnSqYQr3H@Y4Uu/5ZLKXvNKKdiMkv9s/jJ0lqi3KiolgocotDlxcZ5Xx2eo@CHhKRy1mLTVRHZVxfH/8DQ)

*Saved <s>2</s> 8 bytes thanks to @ophact!*
*Saved 6 bytes thanks to @EliteDaMyth!*

---

Returns the resulting text with HTML-formatting applied.

(Ab)uses a RegExp-replacer to modify the picked words. If anyone is interested, I'd be happy to add an explanation, if requested.

---

```js
f=(i,j=p=0,r=_=>Math.random()*3|0,q=_=>p+=4+r()*5,x=q())=>i.replace(/[-'\w]+/g,m=>j++==p?(m[3]?[q(),`<${s="bis"[r()]} style="font:2em monospace;color:rgb(${[r()*85,r()*85,r()*85]})">${m}</${s}>`]:[++p,m])[1]:m).replace(/\n/g,"<br>")

var c = `It was in the morning of June 21, and I had just set
paw in the office. Right away I could tell it wasn't
going to be a good day. My staff was running
around like a pack of rats in a maze. And everyone
was complaining about something.
"Geronimo, the air-conditioner's broken!"
yelled my secretary, Mousella MacMouser.
"Geronimo, we are run out of coffee!" shrieked
Blasco Tabasco, one of my designers.
"Geronimo, the computers are all down!"
cried my proofreader. Mickey Misprint.`;

document.write(f(c));
```

Comment: Wow, that's a lot shorter than mine!

Comment: You can save bytes on your `q` and `c` functions by making them have unused arguments, for example `_=>p+=4+r()*15|0` instead of `()=>p+=4+r()*15|0`.

Comment: @ophact Ah, thanks! :)

Comment: Save another six bytes with  `m[3]` instead of `m.length>3`.

Comment: [232 chars](https://bit.ly/3bDzurX). Changes the random function to multiply by 3 and floor so we dont have to repeat it. Removes the c() function. change `j=0,p=0` to `j=p=0`

Comment: @EliteDaMyth problem is that with your code, only colors with rgb values of multiples of 85.

Comment: You can use [String#fixed()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fixed); [String#big()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/big); [String#fontcolor()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fontcolor) instead of `style=""`

Comment: @ophact, yea because the number from the random function will only be 1,2 or 3.

Comment: Also, doesn't make a difference for length, but you should use `biu` instead of `bis` so underline appears instead of strike-through.

Comment: I found another problem: underscores are not removed from the start and end. Obviously Geronimo books won't contain underscores, but ideally no underscores will be at the start and end.

Comment: [227 bytes](https://tio.run/##VY/BbsIwEETv@YoVQsUmIdDSShXgcKYSl17TqDGJExw5XmMbEKJ8O02Qeuhppd2ZtzMNP3FXWGn8RGMp7hW7Exk1zLBZZNk3S7bc72PLdYktoeP5z4yyhBz6iwnZa2i75Rsl9OlJxlYYxQtBpulk9HXOwmkdtSxpwpAxsyZtOs/W6YHQKF8Nr44NdtIN0s6f3cD5ixJsUKH2ixfRQosanelYywIV2oWtd2R47cXj97fo38hudJAMr@1tNe2otyTPFmkYmqjNaPqcLVoaO6Okz4M8blDqfLWzSX4/cQsFMMg3Hs7cgdTg96L7a7XUNWAFH0ct4OU5gq46bGDPS2iOzoMTPjD8/OfAqpKFiOFT1nsP/MwvnbjAoyrBC6VAPvh65IMae7JH2AngUCOWUPJLDNtLV59X1SOHPeo@QL4MggK1QyVihTWpSEHp8v4L)

Answer (score 2):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), <s>459...</s> 375 bytes

```javascript
m=>`<p>${(g=(t,M=Math.random,c=_=>M()*255|0,o=c(),p=c(),q=c(),y='biu'[M()*3|0],x=(N,F)=>N.replace(/[a-zA-Z]|(?<=[a-zA-Z]).(?=[a-zA-Z])/g,F),T=t.length<20,z=_=>T?0:x(t[B=4+M()*15|0],G=>G)[3]?B:z())=>T?t:(t[C=z()]=x(t[C],Y=>`<${y} style=font-size:20;font-family:sans-serif;color:rgb(${[o,p,q]})>${Y}</${y}>`))&&t.slice(0,20).concat(g(t.slice(20))))(m.split(/\s/)).join` `}</p>`
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZVNRT9swEH7vrzgQos7mpqWMl1K3AqRVTCoPEy@sq1Y3cVLTxBdsh5ICv707Z0LTtDzYuct33/fdOX6Uz9IlVle@ZzBVh0wcSjFZjavJySvLBfN8LubSb2IrTYolT8QvMZmz6NPw4uJtwFEkLOJVuz61ayO6a113FwFz/jZY8hfB7vjXSEzuYquqQiaK9Reyt7/q/Vi@selYfARRzKZ/g35ORfxe@LhQJveb8XDA90H8fjoYvTC/uBZfPgeRs4ugMhOTWbQ4X06vR3sWRQHmR4S6ERQuRSi4WfKH0NrJa/MOzjeFEhka33N6r0bDwWUbZLLURTNy0rieU1ZnlwkWaEc2X7OT1wXyij8t3yOazsP7uB@oJqsoOj31sSs0tTbgw0EUJ2gS6VnOPtKUpIeVsasK7Vn/p@tHUfyI2qxgRUTVZHWgIoeFigvMWcZWtx520oE24DcKSrRGmxwwg2@1UTA840AnArewkSk81s6DU75Tyd1HBWYZKcfwXecbD3InGwInWBcpeFUUoFt@0/WdHAOzR1grkJAjppDKJoZ5Q2OSWdb6sLUJBjrSYk26hd4GcCWTbfBkpW@tSijlnkSvCKKelW3QqE4oT7Cks9dtD3KNNdnFUvkNxXHneKYsGl0ib51LbXs0jFR7TeW262BtcavM0XGnIecqhZKcqcQqL23DYY61o7yEuUzad/sP5Y4YrQoNQNAltwnNRqmjY3Abq9VWpZ3rgm4Bwr1ch50D6QYg6aTK6ZxcuP9shpZqT19aekkjTXEXTNJ1@uOxsoiZVTIlRzDXyVY1tLnKauNj@m0OvwE)

Wow. Just wow. I'm probably missing a really obvious golf here. This is probably the longest program I have ever written, after "Help me count the omer".

### How does this work?

Wraps an immediate invocation of `g`, a recursive function, inside a `p` tag.

In `g`, we initialize multiple arguments: `t`, which is an array of words, `M`, the built-in random function, and then `c` which returns a random integer from 0 to 255. This is followed by three invocations used as the color of the word (each call to `g` only replaces one word). We also set the "effect" used on the modified word. Next, the function `x` is where the magic happens: takes a word and a callback and replaces all alphabetical letters and special characters sandwiched between alphabetical letters with a call to the callback. I'm not a regular expressions expert, but luckily I knew enough about lookbehinds and lookaheads to implement the `replace`. This saved 47 bytes because before I was using a lengthy `test` condition.

We also create `z` which finds a random number whose corresponding word has at least 4 characters.

Function body: if the length of `t` is less than 20, return `t` unchanged, otherwise set `t[C=z()]`  (the random word) to a call to `x` with that word and a special HTML generator as a callback. We also use an `&&` so that rather than returning an assignment, we return a concatenation of the new `t` and a recursive call with `t.slice(20)`. Note that using spread operators saves no bytes.

`g` is then invoked with `m.split(/\s/)` and joined with a space.